# install make in redhat - make command not found

Tags: linux, redhat

```
-bash: make: command not found
[root@Ritely r2]#
```

I am using redhat and I need to install make. any help please.
I am setting up a vps server and need to install python:

```
$ cd reddit/r2
$ make pyx
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py develop
$ make
```

it says that make is not found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`make` is in the `make` package, part of the "Development Tools" group which you should install before attempting to build anything.

Comment: `sudo subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms` Notice this is for version 8, change to match your version.

Answer (score 6):

if your question is how to install make on redhat then you can do it using command `yum install make`. 
if yum not work then try to set proxy URL to the proxy server in file `/etc/yum.conf`.